# Relative paths depend on where I run the python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, relative-path

So I have this font `./files/resources/COMIC.TTF`

And I reference the font like this: `font = pygame.font.Font('./files/resources/COMIC.TTF', 12)`

So I ran this on cmd `python files/opencv_ball_tracker.py` and sure enough it works.

But when I `cd files` then run `python opencv_ball_tracker.py` it fails with `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './files/resources/COMIC.TTF'`.

How do I make it so that it works no matter where I run the file?

Answer (score 1):

you could use the absolute pathing, so if your using windows use "C:/XXX/XXX/files/resources/COMIC.TTF".

for linux/MAC it would be same but change the C:/ to the respective one for UNIX machines (I know for Mac it would be /Users/XXX/files/resources/COMIC.TTF)

Edit: If you wanted to use relative pathing I think you would need to copy the files folder with the python script and run it with the folder in there OR add it to your python pathing

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is to use `pathlib`. The syntax is a little unusual, but it does what you need. I'm assuming here that the file you are executing is run at the root.

```
from pathlib import Path
font_path = Path(__file__).parent / "files" / "resources" / "COMIC.TTF"
font_absolute_path = font_path.absolute()
print(font_absolute_path)
```